# What does --force-queryable flag mean in adb install?

Tags: android, shell, installation, adb

I'm looking at [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner#enable-command) to understand how to use the `androidx.test.services` package, and I was wondering if anybody would happen to know what the `--force-queryable` flag meant in the following lines

```
FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION=""
if [[ $DEVICE_API_LEVEL -ge 30 ]]; then
   FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION="--force-queryable"
fi

...

# Install the test orchestrator.
adb install $FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION -r path/to/m2repository/androidx/test/orchestrator/1.4.2/orchestrator-1.4.2.apk

# Install test services.
adb install $FORCE_QUERYABLE_OPTION -r path/to/m2repository/androidx/test/services/test-services/1.4.2/test-services-1.4.2.apk
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've looked at documentation for the command line and online, but I couldn't find much information.

Answer (score 1):

The `--force-queryable` is related to changes introduced in Android 12 (API level 30) and above.

Starting from Android 12, Google introduced a security feature called `queryable` for installed packages. This feature restricts the ability of other apps to query certain information about the installed packages. However, in testing scenarios, it may be necessary for testing frameworks or services to query information about the installed packages.

The `--force-queryable` is a way to override this restriction during the installation of the test orchestrator and test services. By including this flag, you are essentially telling the system to allow queries on the installed packages for testing purposes.